# Error: Invalid raw at template Element Cooked Validator

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

While parsing the JSX component, I'm trying to replace classNames as string literals.

```
traverse(ast, {
    JSXAttribute(path) {
      if (
        path.node.name.name === "className" &&
        path.node.value &&
        path.node.value.type === "StringLiteral"
      ) {
        const classNames = path.node.value.value.split(" ");
        const updatedClassNames = classNames.map((className) => {
          return cssModule[className] ? `\${1}` : className;
        });

        path.node.value = t.jsxExpressionContainer(
          t.templateLiteral(
            [
              t.templateElement(
                {
                  raw: updatedClassNames.join(" "),
                  cooked: updatedClassNames.join(" "),
                },
                false
              ),
            ],
            []
          )
        );
      }
    },
  });
```

This code works when I don't put `$` and `{` beside each other.

I'm unable to figure out how to accomplish this.
Thanks in advance for any help!